# Apply Filer, Search and Print

Tags: csv, filter

I am a newbie to PowerShell
I need to know how do I apply the filter to date column of an imported CSV file with more than 6 columns. 
And Search for a specific value in another column. 
Then Print the rows if the searched value if present.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it using similar to below:

Import-Csv "t.csv" | ? Classification -like "Tool" | Export-csv -Notypeinformation "filtered.csv"

## Remove_Older_Records

$Data = Import-CSV "filtered.csv"
$CutoffDate = (Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
$Data | Where-Object {$_.Date -as [datetime] -ge $CutoffDate} | Export-csv -notypeinformation "filtered_date.csv"

## Sortandremoveduplicates

$input = "filtered_date.csv"
$inputCsv = Import-Csv $input | Sort-Object 'Device Name' -Unique

$inputCsv | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "filtered_date_Unique.csv"